# wordpress mysql / wpdb ajax load more for terms help

Tags: custom-taxonomy, ajax, jquery, mysql, wpdb

Can anyone pls assist me with my problem. I am not asking for code, but even some guidance as to how to get this working. I have tried many ways, to get my terms to load using ajax load more  and seem to keep having a difficulty with it. The reason for the issue is that i have used $wpdb rather than $wp_query for the data retrieval. Also, I am retrieving terms, not posts. I have ajax load more working for posts, but the same functions cannot be used for wpdb data.

I find all product category ( terms ) from a custom taxonomy ( workplaces ). I then just want to have the terms load more on the same page rather than normal pagination. ( I have acheived regular pagination but have removed it from here ). I am attempting just a regular load more button, before I change it to infinite.

The load more button is getting stuck on Loading... & nothing changes.

This is my function to get the initial query, with a limit of 3 to be displayed:

```
function get_product_categories_from_a_product_workplace_all( $workplace_term_slug, $taxonomy = 'workplaces' ) {
        global $wpdb;
        global $wp_query;
        //get the total amount of terms
        $total_query = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
        FROM    {$wpdb->prefix}terms t1
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt1
            ON  t1.term_id = tt1.term_id 
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr1
            ON  tt1.term_taxonomy_id = tr1.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr2
            ON  tr1.object_id = tr2.object_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt2
            ON  tr2.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id         
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t2
            ON  tt2.term_id = t2.term_id
        WHERE tt1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
        AND tt2.taxonomy = '$taxonomy'
        AND  t2.slug = '$workplace_term_slug' ) AS a
        ");       
        $post_per_page  = 3;
       //get the terms, with a limit of 3
        $query = ( "
            SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
            FROM    {$wpdb->prefix}terms t1
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt1
                ON  t1.term_id = tt1.term_id 
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr1
                ON  tt1.term_taxonomy_id = tr1.term_taxonomy_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr2
                ON  tr1.object_id = tr2.object_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt2
                ON  tr2.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id         
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t2
                ON  tt2.term_id = t2.term_id
            WHERE tt1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
            AND tt2.taxonomy = '$taxonomy'
            AND  t2.slug = '$workplace_term_slug' 
            LIMIT $post_per_page  
                 
        " );
        $wpdb->show_errors();         
        $test=   $wpdb->get_results( $query );
            echo '<div class=" woocommerce columns-5"><ul class=" products columns-5">';
        foreach($test as $value){
          $wp_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['workplaces'];   
          $cat_slug = $value->slug;                        
          $cat_name = $value->name;
    
          echo '<li class="product-category product"><div class="banner-box"> 
         <div class="banner-box__image"> 
         <a href="' . esc_url ( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) ) . '/'. 'product-category'. '/' . esc_html($cat_slug) . '?workplaces=' . esc_html($wp_slug) . '"';
          echo theme_woo_subcategory_thumbnail( $value);          
          echo '</a></div><div class="banner-box__info"><a href="' . 
          get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/'. 'product-category'. '/' . esc_html($cat_slug) . '?workplaces=' . esc_html($wp_slug) . '/' . '">' . '<h2 itemprop="name" class="woocommerce-loop-category__title"><span>' . esc_html($cat_name) . '</a></span></h2></li>';  
     
        }
        
        echo '</ul>';
        ?>
        <div class="loadmore">
          <input type="button" id="loadBtn" value="Load More">
          <input type="hidden" id="row" value="0">
          <input type="hidden" id="postCount" value="<?php echo $total_query; ?>">
        </div> 

    }
<?php

    function db_workplace(){

        if (isset($_POST['row'])) {
            $start = $_POST['row'];
            $limit = 3;
            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
            FROM    {$wpdb->prefix}terms t1
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt1
                ON  t1.term_id = tt1.term_id 
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr1
                ON  tt1.term_taxonomy_id = tr1.term_taxonomy_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr2
                ON  tr1.object_id = tr2.object_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt2
                ON  tr2.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id         
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t2
                ON  tt2.term_id = t2.term_id
            WHERE tt1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
            AND tt2.taxonomy = '$taxonomy'
            AND  t2.slug = '$workplace_term_slug'
            LIMIT ".$start.",".$limit;

            $result = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while ($row = $wpdb->get_row( $query )) {
                ?>
<!--for testing purposes i just want to get the term_id to show so I know it's working but when i get it working properly it will be the html as before -->
                <div class="post"><?php echo $row['term_id']; ?></div>
              <?php }
            }
          }


    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore-data', 'db_workplace'); // wp_ajax_{action}
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore-data', 'db_workplace'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
```

I think this is where my problem lies. I am not sure how to set up the ajax data for the retrieval of more terms

```
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpb_hook_load' );
function wpb_hook_load() {
      ?>
      <script>
         jQuery(document).ready(function () {
           jQuery(document).on('click', '#loadBtn', function () {
           var row = Number(jQuery('#row').val());
           var count = Number(jQuery('#postCount').val());
           var limit = 3;
           row = row + limit;
           jQuery('#row').val(row);
           jQuery("#loadBtn").val('Loading...');
 
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://stagingwebsite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        action: 'loadmore-data',
        data: 'row=' + row,
        success: function (data) {
          var rowCount = row + limit;
          jQuery('.postList').append(data);
          if (rowCount >= count) {
            jQuery('#loadBtn').css("display", "none");
          } else {
            jQuery("#loadBtn").val('Load More');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: have you considered using the already existing REST API to pull in the terms? Then creating the HTML on the client side? This way you could use something already built into WordPress and delete your AJAX PHP code. As a bonus, building the HTML in javascript would be faster and more secure. Just make sure your custom taxonomy has `show_in_rest` set to true when it's registered, I suspect it'll be available at `/wp-json/wp/v2/workplaces`. Also why are you fetching terms using WPDB instead of the term fetching functions? Also the code in your Q is not indented properly, making it hard to read

Comment: by term fetching functions, do you mean get_the_term() from posts?

Comment: will look into the REST API, haven't worked with it yet. thanks

Comment: yes, or functions such as https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/ or using `WP_Term_Query` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/get_terms/